# phpmailer присылает пустое письмо

Tags: php, phpmailer

Все срабатывает, но приходит письмо пустое. Подскажите в чем проблема

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$texts = $_POST['texts'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;// Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();// Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;// Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'test2@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = '1231231231231'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';// Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;//TCP port to connect to/этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('test2@mail');// от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('test@mail.ru');// Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');// Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');// Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');// Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);// Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body = '' .$name. ' оставил заявку, его почта ' .$email. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$texts;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Error';
} else {
echo 'Спасибо. Я отвечу Вам в ближайшее время';
}
?>
```

html

```
<form action="src/php/mail.php " 
      id="contact__form " 
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p class="inp__title ">Остались вопросы? Напишите мне!</p>
   <input type="text " name="name " class="inp__name " placeholder="Имя: " />
   <input type="mail " name="email " class="inp__mail " placeholder="Почта: " />
   <textarea name="texts " class="inp__text "></textarea>
   <button type="submit " class="inp__subm ">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас пробелы в `name` - наверное, из-за этого. То есть, не `name="texts "`, а нужно везде `name="texts"`, и с остальными name подобно этому.

) или добавьте везде нужные пробелы:

```
$name = $_POST['name '];
$email = $_POST['email '];
$texts = $_POST['texts '];
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего файл шаблона не подключён, потому что в строке

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($generator_file_content,$generatorId ."html");
```

неверно указано имя файла. Попробуйте заменить на:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($generator_file_content,$generatorId .".html");
```